# Function painting "Dependent cells" on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to implement in my DataGridView a feature similar to "Dependent cells" from MsExcel like on the following picture.
The best would be some kind of painting function that would take destination and dependent datagridviewcell addresses as parameters and paint the arrow over datagridview.
Any idea how to do it?

[image: Excel table with]

Comment: Use a 3rd-party library like DevExpress.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @UweKeim but DevExpress licence is like 900$, so unfortunately it's not really an option for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Paint` event to do the drawing.

Let's assume you have collected the cells to connect in a `List<T>`:

```
List<Tuple<DataGridViewCell, DataGridViewCell>> DgvCells =
                             new List<Tuple<DataGridViewCell, DataGridViewCell>>();
```

Now you can code the DGV's `Paint` event to do the drawing, maybe like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    foreach(var t in DgvCells)
    {
        if (!(t.Item1.Displayed && t.Item2.Displayed)) continue;
        Point p1 = GetCenter(dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
                                           t.Item1.ColumnIndex, t.Item1.RowIndex, true));
        Point p2 = GetCenter(dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
                                           t.Item2.ColumnIndex, t.Item2.RowIndex, true));
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1) 
              { EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor })
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
    }
}
```

It uses a tiny helper function:

```
Point GetCenter(Rectangle r)
{ return new Point(r.X + r.Width / 2, r.Y + r.Height / 2); }
```

I have added code in the CellMouseClick event to add to the list. The result looks like this:

[image]

You can add code to style the drawing, like adding a `StartCap` or use different colors etc..

As usual you need to call `Invalidate()` on the `DGV` whenever you add or remove elements from the list of cells to connect.

Note that this is just a minimal example. You will want to add code to catch various errors or decide what to do when one of the cells is not displayed. (I simply hide the line then..)

When **srcolling** you will have to `Invalidate` the DGV, too!